# HTML - JavaScript - Adding and Deleting/Hiding Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my website the user is going to select an image, that image will then be inserted into a div tag. I need it so when the user clicks the image that was inserted into the div then it will be removed (deleted or hidden) from the div. I've tried:

```
document.getElementById("elementId").style.display = "none";
```

and other similar things. I really just cant get this to work please help!

HTML + JavaScript code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <script>
        var cardNumber = 1;
        var deck = [];

        var addCard = function(cardName)
        {   
            if("undefined" != document.getElementById("card" + cardNumber).value)
            {
                if(deck.indexOf(cardName) > -1)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    if(deck.length != 1)
                    {
                        deck.push(cardName);
                        document.getElementById("card" + cardNumber).innerHTML = '<img id = "' + cardName + '" class = "deckCardSize" onclick = updateCards(' + cardName + ') src = "Images/Cards/' + cardName + '.png">';
                        cardNumber += 1;
                    }
                    if(deck.length >= 1)
                    {
                        cardNumber = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "card1" class = "cards"></div>
    <div id = "1">
        <img class = "cardSize" onclick = "addCard('Archer')" src = "Images/Cards/Archer.png">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS Code:

```
.cards
{
    height:150px;
    width:125px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:6.2%;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    border:5px solid #ff6666;
    background-color:#ff6666;
}
.cardSize
{
    height:150px;
    width:125px;
    float:left;
    margin-left:7%;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Comment: what does your `updateCards` function do?

Comment: the updateCards function does not do anything yet. It's supposed to remove a card once clicked on in the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the `img` by `id`.

Also fix the issue with the `updateCards` function:

```
document.getElementById("card" + cardNumber).innerHTML = '<img id = "' + cardName + '" class = "deckCardSize" onclick = "updateCards(\'' + cardName + '\')" src = "' + cardName + '.png">';
```

For example,

```
 <div id="card1" class="cards">
    <img id="Archer" class="deckCardSize"    onclick="updateCards('Archer')" src="Archer.png">
 </div>
```

Then just remove the `div` with `id="Archer"`:

```
document.getElementById("Archer").remove();
```

FYI, I added a simple `updateCards` function that just hides the `img` instead of removing it entirely :

```
    var updateCards = function(cardName) {
        document.getElementById(cardName).style.display = 'none';
    }
```

Comment: your edited version of this answer (current) did not work. I tried that before. The previous answer you gave was correct. adding the image to a div in a div the removing the image by its div id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach a click event listener to a class that is applied to all inserted images.  the function that the listener fires would then apply `css.style.display = "none"` to `this`

Comment: whenever I tried using css.style.display = "none"; it always gave me the error:

Comment: an error that said: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Answer (score 0):

First, remove all spaces between attributes and its values (I mean everywhere in your code), that is:

```
<div id="card1" class="cards"></div><!-- correct -->
<div id = "card1" class = "cards"></div><!-- incorrect -->
```

Second, you have an error in your code here:

```
document.getElementById("card" + cardNumber).innerHTML = '<img id = "' + cardName + '" class = "deckCardSize" onclick = updateCards(' + cardName + ') src = "Images/Cards/' + cardName + '.png">';
```

You have missed double quotes around `onclick`'s value. Replace it with this:

```
document.getElementById("card" + cardNumber).innerHTML = '<img id="' + cardName + '" class="deckCardSize" onclick="updateCards(' + cardName + ')" src="Images/Cards/' + cardName + '.png">';
```

Also, you have to define function `updateCards(name)`, it maybe empty, but it must exists. If it doesn't exists, than any javascript code will stops running after you clicked on that image.

Third, `<div id = "1">` has an error too. `id` attribute **must** starts from a letter.

---

here is working code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="test.css">
    <script>
        var cardNumber = 1;
        var deck = [];

        function addCard(cardName) {   
            if ("undefined" != document.getElementById("card" + cardNumber).value) {
                if (deck.indexOf(cardName) > -1) {

                } else {
                    if (deck.length != 1) {
                        deck.push(cardName);
                        document.getElementById("card" + cardNumber).innerHTML = '<img id="img' + cardName + '" class="deckCardSize" onclick="updateCards(\'' + cardName + '\')" src="Images/Cards/' + cardName + '.png">';
                        cardNumber += 1;
                    }
                    if (deck.length >= 1) {
                        cardNumber = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        function updateCards(cardName) {
            //some work
            document.getElementById("img" + cardName).remove();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="card1" class="cards"></div>
    <div id="main1">
        <img class="cardSize" onclick="addCard('Archer')" src="Images/Cards/Archer.png">
    </div>
</body>
```

Tested and worked!

Comment: 1. the spaces in my code are for my readability and it doesn't affect the code at all. 2. that "error" you were talking about is actually a variable being passed in. I need the value there. but thanks. 3. updateCards(cardName) is a function but i didnt include it in the code because nothing is in it yet because thats why i asked the question, to know what to put in it.

Comment: @Jordan, your "readability" is really *bad* practice, I strongly suggest you to not to use it anymore =). 2. I'm talking not about variable `cardName`, I'm talking about **attributes** and its **values**. `onclick` - is attribute and its value (in your case `updateCards(' + cardName + ')`) **must** be enclosed with double quotes.

Comment: the variable being passed into the function called cardName is becoming the img id in the case you stated above so therefore it does not need to be enclosed in double quotes. If i did then the id would be cardName not the value of cardName.

Comment: @Jordan, you **must** enclose it, because this rule comes from the valid xml markup rules. Take a closer look - I think you didn't see about what quotes I'm talking. Btw, I've found yet another error in this place =). Look. You wrote: `onclick = updateCards(' + cardName + ')` and in the resulting **innerHTML** it will give the result of `onclick = updateCards(Archer)`. And this result has **two** errors. It **must** be `onclick="updateCards('Archer')"` in order to work! So take a closer look at my updated answer, how to make it.